# How to pass BuildContext without 'JsObject' error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, typeerror

I'm developing a Flutter application and encountered an issue when trying to use the `showDialog` function. The compiler throws an error stating that the argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'. I suspect the issue arises from a misunderstanding of how to correctly pass the `BuildContext` or possibly due to an incorrect import.

**Error Message:**

```
 The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type
 'BuildContext'.
```

**What I've tried:**

1. Removing the `import dart:js`; line, thinking it might be causing conflicts with the `BuildContext` type.
2. Aliasing the import as `context` using `import 'dart:js' as context;`, but the issue persists.
3. Considering passing the `BuildContext` explicitly or using a null assertion operator (`!`), but I'm unsure if that's the right approach or how to properly implement it.

**Code Snippet:**

```
import 'dart:js';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

showDataAlert() {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
           // AlertDialog content
        );
      });
}
```

**Questions:**

- How should I correctly pass the `BuildContext` to `showDialog` to avoid this type conflict?
- Is the `import 'dart:js'`; line relevant to this issue, and how should I handle it if so?
- Are there best practices for using `BuildContext` in such scenarios that I might be overlooking?

I have searched Stack Overflow for similar issues but found none that address the specific type mismatch error with `BuildContext` and `JsObject`. I appreciate any guidance on resolving this issue. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First delete `"import 'dart:js` and save the file. then Pass context on method.

```dart
showDataAlert(BuildContext context) {
```

Save again, run the app. If fails do `flutter clean` and rebuild the app.